# Gyro Gearloose and Artificial Grass

Tags: story-identification, comics, disney, donald-duck

I'm looking for a classic Disney book or comic in which Gyro Gearloose replaces all of Uncle Scrooge's (or perhaps Donald's) annoyances with synthetic substitutes — including replacing the grass of the lawn with Astroturf (no need to mow it!).  Most of the substitutes were robotic, including gardening robots.

I remember this story from the '70s but I cannot find any record or mention of it.  Any ideas or sources?

Answer (score 4):

The book is '[Mickey and the Really Neat Robot](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/17191271-mickey-mouse-and-the-really-neat-robot)' (1970, Disney).

It is Mickey's lawn, not Donald's, that is replaced with green concrete (not Astroturf). The robot does belong to Gyro Gearloose.

---

[image]